# how to create a Mysql dynamic query statement with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

I'm trying to create a dynamic query statement with some condition for Mybatis.

This is not working query statement but this describes my current conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM myTemp WHERE name="Jin" if (
(name is null AND type = 0 ANd status = 2) OR (name is NOT NULL AND 
type = 0 AND status =2 ) );
```

assume, the value "name" is dynamic value and if the name is not empty(not null) then execute a query with name value such as,

```
SELECT * FROM myTemp Where type = 0 AND status = 2 AND name ="someValue"
```

else if the name is empty or null then execute a query without name value such as,

```
SELECT * FROM myTemp where type = 0 AND status = 2.
```

How can I make a MySQL query statement with above conditions?

Comment: Why wouldn't this work: `SELECT * FROM myTemp Where type = 0 AND status = 2` ?? . This should consider all the cases (with name or without name)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `someValue` in the example above is provided as a parameter to you query and it may be `null`? And if it is `null` you want to execute the query without any predicate on `name` column, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use COALESCE function to select first non-null value. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTemp Where type = 0 AND status = 2 AND name = COALESCE("someValue", name)
```

This way, if you give "someValue", it will be matched to name. If you give NULL instead of "someValue", it will match to name which is always equal.

Comment: If the `name` is `NULL` in database this query will not return anything as `NULL = NULL` is always false.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTemp
WHERE type = 0 AND status = 2 AND (name = "someValue" OR name IS NULL)
```